# How to get a dictionary from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to Python and stuck at something basic.

Say there's a list of dictionaries as follows:

```
[{key1:value1},{key2:value2},...{keyn:valuen}]
```

is there a pythonic way of extracting the dictionary

```
{key1:value1},{key2:value2},...{keyn:valuen}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you mean that you want `{key1: value1, key2:value2, keyn:valuen}`. That is, you want to combine all the separate dictionaries into a single one with each of the keys and values from the individual dictionaries.

Here's how I'd do it, using a dictionary comprehension:

```
 l = [{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"},{"keyn":"valuen"}]
 result = {k:v for d in l for k, v in d.iteritems()}

 print result # {'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1', 'keyn': 'valuen'}
```

Comment: I would prefer a solution not so much looking at the content level of the dictionaries: untested: result = l.pop(): for d in l: result.update(d)

Answer (score 1):

Same thing, in perhaps an easier way to read:

```
result = {}
d_list = [{"key1": "value1"}, {"key2": "value2"}, {"keyn": "valuen"}]
for d in d_list:
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        result[k] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[{1:1},{2:2},{3:3}]

result=dict([(k,v) for x in a for k,v in x.items()])
print result //{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```